# How does one say 'a more extensive treatment'?

Tags: single-word-requests

There are a couple ways to ask this question. I'll provide some examples.

> "For more on this topic, go to __."

> "For a more extensive treatment, cf __."

What I want to express is the idea: "For something which just has straight up more words on this particular topic, so that there is a higher chance that one of the ideas present there is memorable, or just so that you can have a longer experience reading something on this topic" using something like:

> "For a longer __ on the subject, please go here."

But which also carries roughly the same meaning when used alone and without context. (This is a strange requirement, I know). Thus, words like 'discussion,' or 'treatment' itself don't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Surely the purpose of an 'elaboration' or 'expanded or extended treatment' is more than just to give someone a "longer reading experience."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to answer based on the assumption that the example sentences are not *exact* and that a drop-in word can be prefaced by an article or pronoun. (It may even be the case that you don't necessarily intend the word to be dropped into the underlined parts following *go to* and *cf* in the first two examples, but to replace their earlier phrases.)

I'm also going to assume that you're looking for a single word (a noun) that does not *require* an adjective. So, the single word itself implies a long or detailed discussion—even when used without anything else. (Therefore, *treatment* wouldn't work because it would require *more extensive* in front of it.)

Lastly, I'm going to assume that you want a word that can not only imply something *more than* what has gone before, but can imply something detailed in its own right even if a "shorter" version has not been given that it would be relative to.

[**Disquisition**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/disquisition):

> A long or elaborate essay or discussion on a particular subject.
>
> "Nothing can kill a radio show quicker than a disquisition on intertextual analysis."
>
> "We find textbooks, readers, grammars; learned articles on scientific subjects; disquisitions on culture and public policy; even an ambitious early novel-all still virtually unknown today."
>
> "He has produced a book chock-full of affecting vignettes, and that rarest of treats - an informed disquisition about public policy wrapped up in a fascinating narrative."
>
> "Enthusiastically, I launched into a disquisition on how useful they were for marking out trails when hiking… until I realised that I was getting a very funny look."

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**comprehensive**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/comprehensive)

> 1. So large in scope or content as to include much: a comprehensive history of the revolution.
> 2. Marked by or showing extensive understanding;  synonyms:  exhaustive, encyclopedic

As in:

> "For a **comprehensive** read on the subject, please go here."

Comment: This doesn’t seem to fit the example sentences

Answer (score 0):

> "For a longer ***treatise*** on the subject, please go here."

Wikipedia:

> A **[treatise](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treatise)** is a formal and systematic written discourse on
>   some subject, generally longer and treating it in greater depth than
>   an essay, and more concerned with investigating or exposing the
>   principles of the subject.

Collins:

> **[treatise](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/treatise)**
>
> *countable noun*
>
> A treatise is a long, formal piece of writing about a particular
>   subject.
>
> ...Locke's Treatise on Civil Government.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers

Also, ***exposition***.

> "For a longer ***exposition*** on the subject, please go here."

Collins:

> **[exposition](https://www.google.co.in/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/amp/english/exposition)**
>
> **1**. *countable noun*
>
> An exposition of an idea or theory is a detailed explanation
>   or account of it.
>
> [*formal*]
>
> A long exposition of the new republican ideas would be tiresome.
>
> COBUILD Advanced English Dictionary. Copyright © HarperCollins
>   Publishers